# PHP - Check how many values in array

Tags: php, arrays

Can I check the number of values in an array,
for example...

```
$abc=array();

$abc[0]="asd";
$abc[1]="sadaf";
$abc[2]="sfadaf";
```

I want to check and store it(2) in a variable that array abc[] exists till $abc[2]..

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`count`](http://docs.php.net/count) or [`sizeof`](http://docs.php.net/sizeof) for the total number of values or [`array_count_values`](http://docs.php.net/array_count_values) to count the frequency of each value.

Answer (score 10):

There is [count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arraysize = sizeof($abc) - 1; // will be set to 2
if(isset($abc[$arraysize]))
{
   $abcEndExists = true;
}
else
{
    $abcEndExists = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$minArrayIndex  = 2;
$arrayCountTest = ((count($abc) - 1) >= $minArrayIndex) ? true : false;
```

This will assign `$arrayCountTest` true if the array has elements of at least an index of 2.